# Why my files are not readable in Linux and get the Path error?

Tags: ubuntu, kubernetes, crunchy-postgresql-operator

I am trying to install PGO (Postgres Operator) in k8s. I am following [this](https://access.crunchydata.com/documentation/postgres-operator/5.3.0/quickstart/) documentation.
At the 2nd step when I run following command

```
kubectl apply --server-side -k kustomize/install/default
```

I see error

> master-k8s@masterk8s-virtual-machine:~/postgres-operator-examples-main$ kubectl apply --server-side -k kustomize/install/default
> error: containers path is not of type []interface{} but map[string]interface {}

**System Specifications:**

- I have k8s 2 node cluster with one master node.
- All running Ubuntu 20.4

**What I have try:**

- I download repository again without clone and directory uploaded on master node
- I try to provide full path and this time I received the same error
- I checked the default directory there 2 files present
- I try to run this command inside the directory.

**What Do I need?**

I am looking for solution why I am not able to follow the 2nd step of document.
Please help me to find what did I missed or doing it wrong.

I really thankful.

**Update Question:**

I updated the version of k8s and kustomize and still see the same issue.

```
master-k8s@masterk8s-virtual-machine:~/test/postgres-operator-examples-main$ kubectl apply --server-side -k kustomize/install/default
error: containers path is not of type []interface{} but map[string]interface {}
```

**Kustomize version:**

```
{Version:kustomize/v4.5.7 GitCommit:56d82a8xxxxxxxxxxxxx BuildDate:2022-08-02T16:35:54Z GoOs:linux GoArch:amd64}
```

Comment: What version of Kubernetes are you using? I just tried this with 1.24. Works fine.  The error seams to me caused by api version of Kubernetes which is not compatible.

Comment: This is my K8s version            Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18", GitVersion:"v1.18.2-0-g52c56ce", GitCommit:"592b165", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-07-14T05:27:34Z", GoVersion:"go1.13.8", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"26", GitVersion:"v1.26.0", GitCommit:"b46a3f887", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2022-12-08T19:51:45Z", GoVersion:"go1.19.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}

Comment: And this is my kustomize version         {Version:kustomize/v4.5.7 GitCommit:56d82axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx BuildDate:2022-08-02T16:35:54Z GoOs:linux GoArch:amd64}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To fix your issue make sure kubectl integration like below :**

As **@Ralle** commented, Check versions. **Kustomize v2.1.0 and v3.0.0+, and is included in kubectl 1.21+**, for more information please look at the [Kustomize doesn't work with CRDs when specifying images](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/107751).

**Update :** The kustomize build flow at v2.0.3 was added to kubectl v1.14. The kustomize flow in kubectl remained frozen at v2.0.3 until kubectl v1.21, which [updated it to v4.0.5](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/4d75a6238a6e330337526e0513e67d02b1940b63/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.21.md#kustomize-updates-in-kubectl). It will be updated on a regular basis going forward, Check your versions & updates in the Kubernetes release notes.
[image]

For examples and guides for using the kubectl integration please see the [kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/kustomization/).

Also check [Kubernetes 1.22: Server Side Apply moves to GA](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2021/08/06/server-side-apply-ga/) for more information.

Comment: Just download this [script](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/blob/master/hack/install_kustomize.sh) and then run:

./install_kustomize.sh [WANTED_VERSION] and also this [link](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/3189) these may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: I just upgraded the kubernetes version and now I am using v1.26.0. I also installed kustomize latest version V4.5.7. I still see the same issue.

Comment: Oh, Try this [Link](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/890).